# Is there any software to copy defined parts of a html page?

Tags: html, templates

I'm changing the template of my old website and, unfortunately, it is static and I need to change the code for every page. Is there software or trick that I can use to help me do it automatically? For example, if using software, I would like to be able to tell the software which parts to keep and which parts to copy from the new layout.

Comment: The best (and, I'm afraid, the only) tool for this job is *you*.

Comment: Err, why not use some kind of non-static solution to fill in templates for you? If you really have to serve it statically, you could crawl the site to extract the static pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Template::Extract](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aExtract) will let you write a template in TT2 syntax and use it to extract data from documents into a data structure. You can then use [TT2](http://template-toolkit.org/) to put that data structure back into a different template (or you can so something else with the data, such as storing it in a database for later use).

Comment: It is a library, not a program. After installing it (which is best done with cpan-minus or another cpan package installer), you write a template that describes your current page structure, then write a program (in Perl) to use that template with the library to get a data structure and so something with it. See the [synopsis](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aExtract#SYNOPSIS) in the manual for Template::Extract for an example. This isn't a ready to run solution, it just does about 3/4 of the work of getting the data for you.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver can do pretty powerful search and replace across an entire web site. If your existing pages are ruthlessly consistent, a sequence of search and replace can turn old site into new.

If you had built your site with Dreamweaver templates then you can [apply a revised template to update the entire site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7a98a.html).  So what you can do is make a .dwt template for your new site design, then perform some search and replaces to add the special comments that make your existing pages appear to be using that .dwt, then tell Dreamweaver to update and all your pages will get the template applied. Sounds crazy but I've actually done that for a multi-thousand page site.

Both are pretty fiddly but at least you can see it happen. You can also run complicated search & replace commands from the command line in Linux using tools like perl. But if you're going to master perl then the Template::Extract module as @Quentin recommended is a better way to do it.

You can also use XSLT to transform your pages to the new appearance. XSLT is out of favor these days and hard to learn, but it operates on nested tags with attributes and so is more aware of HTML structure than search and replace. [Here's a guide to converting to XML and then transforming.](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/08/30/xsltandhtml/)

The trendy way to do it is to read in your HTML document in a browser (or something like node.js), transform it by manipulating the DOM, then save the new document as HTML. W3Schools has a very gentle introduction at "HTML DOM - Change HTML Elements", but most people would use jQuery to fiddle with the DOM. There's a great example of exactly this at *(Stackoverflow limits me to two links, sorry* 2ality.com under the title "Transforming HTML with Node.js and jQuery".

None of this is easy, and arguably it should be. A DOM-based search and replace would be pretty cool feature in an HTML editor, but I don't know that anyone's implemented it.